Why It doesn't show this to the screen
Basically I want show less description and when I press "Read More" I wanna show the full description
The code:
import { useState } from "react";

const JobsListing = ({ job }) => {
  const [showFullDescription, setShowFullDescription] = useState(false);

  let description = job.description;

  if (!showFullDescription) {
    description = description.setstring(0, 90) + "...";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md relative">
        <div className="p-4">
          <div className="mb-6">
            <div className="text-gray-600 my-2">{job.type}</div>
            <h3 className="text-xl font-bold">{job.title}</h3>
          </div>

          <div className="mb-5">{description}</div>

          <h3 className="text-indigo-500 mb-2">{job.salary}</h3>

          <div className="border border-gray-100 mb-5"></div>

          <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between mb-4">
            <div className="text-orange-700 mb-3">
              <i className="fa-solid fa-location-dot text-lg"></i>
              {job.location}
            </div>
            <a
              href={`/job/${job.id}`}
              className="h-[36px] bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-600 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-center text-sm"
            >
              Read More
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default JobsListing;

I expected to show the description from 0, 90 using setstring to show less description also when I click "Read More" I expect to show the full description

What is setstring ?

You seem to have built the logic already, but aren't actually setting showFullDescription anywhere, are you just trying to replace the "Read More" link with a button that toggles the state?

A good title will summarize your question, and help to distinguish your question from other similar questions on this site.  You described your expected results, but didn't describe your actual results.  You should describe why you are convinced that your code should produce the expected results, and why you are convinced that the actual results should not be happening.  This will provide a framework for answerers to highlight any specific misunderstanding or oversight you may have and will result in the best learning experience for you.

What is the setstring property of job.description? The showFullDescription is always false, do you ever call setShowFullDescription to toggle the state value?


You're not toggeling showFullDescription with the button, I've added an onClick()
<button onClick={() => setShowFullDescription(p => !p)}>
    Read More
</button>


Instead of the if at the beginning, use a ternary operator that will render the complete description, or uses substring() to only show the first 50 chars:
{
    (showFullDescription)
        ? job.description
        : job.description.substring(0, 50) + ' ...'
}




Working example:


const { useState } = React;

const JobsListing = () => {
  
  const job = {
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    salary: 1,
    type: 'Job Type',
    title: 'Job Title'
  } 
  const [showFullDescription, setShowFullDescription] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-white rounded-xl shadow-md relative">
        <div className="p-4">
          <div className="mb-6">
            <div className="text-gray-600 my-2">{job.type}</div>
            <h3 className="text-xl font-bold">{job.title}</h3>
          </div>

          <div className="mb-5">
            {
              (showFullDescription)
                ? job.description
                : job.description.substring(0, 50) + ' ...'
            }
          </div>

          <h3 className="text-indigo-500 mb-2">{job.salary}</h3>

          <div className="border border-gray-100 mb-5"></div>

          <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between mb-4">
            <div className="text-orange-700 mb-3">
              <i className="fa-solid fa-location-dot text-lg"></i>
              {job.location}
            </div>
            <button
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescription(p => !p)}>
              Read More
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<JobsListing />, document.getElementById("react"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>



